# Electron build access to static images vue js

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, build, electron

I have a question about linking static images with vuejs in electron.

After I have started the app, it gives me following response:

My project folder is as follows:

```
to-do-desktop:
|
|-.electron-vue
|-build
|-dist
|-node_modules
|-src --> Here is the sourcecode and the index.ejs
|-static --> Here are the images and index.css
|-.babelrc
|-.env
|-.eslintignore
|-.gitignore
|-.travis.yml
|-appveyor.yml
|-package
|-package-lock
|-README.md
|-vue.config
```

My question is now, how can I paste the whole static folder
to the desired destination in the browser. I am using this 
relative path in my vue-File:

```
static/weiss.png
```

I build the app with the following tutorial:

https://auth0.com/blog/electron-tutorial-building-modern-desktop-apps-with-vue-js/

I built it with following command:

```
npm run build
```

What relative path should I use and what conifg settings do I have to do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011372/cordova-android-vue-avd-resource-public-image/61074515#61074515

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011372/cordova-android-vue-avd-resource-public-image/61074515#61074515

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix the problem when I experienced it was to go into the files after the build and convert the paths to relative by adding dots(.), that is:

```
/static/css/randomstring.css
/static/js/randomstring.js
```

to

```
./static/css/randomstring.css
./static/js/randomstring.js
```

this solved the problem without having to change any configs or get new libraries installed.

Comment: This helped me fix my issue where images referenced in Vue templates were not loading from the correct location. A bit strange, but it works in Dev + Build now.